# ERROR! Typed git push ionic master same error from cmd and git bash

Tags: git, github, git-push

[git bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUQbh.png)

I already spent how many minutes figuring this out. I don't know really.

Answer (score 1):

Your error `error: src refspec master does not match any.`

**Case 1:**

It comes when you try to `push` without `committing`

You should `commit` first before pushing

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Some commit name"
git push ionic master
```

Case2:

If you had committed your code try:

```
git push ionic HEAD:master
```

This will push the local reference to remote